# how to read json file in functional component in reactjs and iterate over the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component filter()
My json file has some data which I want to pass into the filter() function and want that function to generate text fields where user can write and submit it. 
So far, I tried to use a map function to read the json file. 
I want to read the line from the map function then check the datatype of the column and make a text field accordingly.

`````
import React, {useState}  from 'react';
import './Form.css';
import data from './data.json'
import axios from 'axios';

const filter= (props) =>{

    const [data,setdata]= useState({
        column:"",
        datatype:""
    });

    {data.map((details,index)=>{
        column= details.column;
        datatype=details.datatype;

        if (props.datatype === "string") {
            return(
                <div>
                <label>
                {props.columns}:
                <br/>
                <input type="text"
                name= {props.columns}
                placeholder={props.columns}/>
                </label> <br/>
                </div>
            );
        }

        if (props.datatype === "date") {
            return(
                <div>
                <label> {props.columns} </label>
                <br/>
                <label> From: </label>
                <input type="date"
                name= {props.columns}
                placeholder="{props.columns}"/>
                <label> To: </label>
                <input type="date"
                name= {props.columns}
                placeholder={props.columns}/>
                </div>
            );
        }

        if (props.datatype === "integer") {
            return(
                <div>
                <label>
                {props.columns}:
                <br/>
                <input type="text"
                name= {props.columns}
                placeholder={props.columns}/>
                </label> <br/>
                </div>
            );
        }

    })}

    return (
       <div> 
           <button>Submit</button> 
        </div>
        );
};

export default filter````



My json data file:

[
    {
      "column": "Name",
      "datatype" : "String"
    },
    {
        "column": "Dob",
        "datatype" : "date"
      }
]


The error I'm getting is :

Line 11:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "filter" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 17:   'keycolumn' is not defined                                                                                                        no-undef
  Line 18:   'datatype' is not defined                                                                                                         no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

The output I expect is: 2 input fields and 1 submit button on the
but because of the error Im not getting anything.
`````

Comment: Seems like you are getting ESlint errors. Update your create-react-app to v3 or just update your ESlint config https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin and next two errors are for variables that you have used but not declared  `const column= details.column;` and `const datatype=details.datatype;`

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to capitalize 'filter' functional component as below:

```
const Filter = props => {...}

export default Filter;
```

Also, make sure you are running with latest version of React that support State Hooks.

Comment: Thanks! First part of the error is removed. But the next two errors still remain. Line 17:  'keycolumn' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 18:  'datatype' is not defined   no-undef

Comment: The error suggest that you have not initialised the variables column and datatype and assigning the values on them. Please refer this link for better understanding of state hooks. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html